# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Using variable outside a function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this TypeFilter

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(ValidateRolesFilter), Arguments = new object[] {
      configuration["key"], RoleGlobals.SystemAdministrator
})]
public IActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

In the class constructor above, I have declared configuration like this

```
public HomeController(IApplicationUserClient getUserClient, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this.getUserClient = getUserClient;
    this.configuration = configuration;
}
```

However, when I try to declare configuration["Item"], in my typefilter, it won't let me. I can only do it inside functions.

What can I do to make it so that I can use my configuration variable outside the function? I tried making it a constant but it didn't work because it reads from appsettings.json.

Comment: What do you mean outside the function?  Do you mean inside another method inside your class?

Comment: I've edited my question. If you see where my typefilter sits, its outside the About function/method. I can't access the configuration variable from there.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `configuration["key"]` in the attribute?  What is the key value suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(ValidateRolesFilter), Arguments = new object[] {
  configuration["key"], RoleGlobals.SystemAdministrator})]
```

The line above it what is called an [Attributes (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/).  Attributes are compile time directives that can read at runtime.

The variable `configuration["key"]` is loaded at run-time.  Therefore the compiler will fail.

Here is another design.  Instantiate the `ValidateRolesFilter` in your constructor.

```
public HomeController(IApplicationUserClient getUserClient, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this.getUserClient = getUserClient;
    this.configuration = configuration;

    // This is just a guess; I have no idea what this object is
    this.canAccessAbout = new ValidateRolesFilter(configuration["key"], RoleGlobals.SystemAdministrator);
}
```

Then in your About method:

```
public IActionResult About()
{
    // again, this is just a guess 
    if (this.canAccessAbout.Validate())
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        // redirect them or display error page
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to read a key from my appsettings.json. The typefilter is located in a generic class so other applications will use it. Unfortunately that means I can't declare the key inside the filter itself. Is there a way I can push appsettings.json items into this filter?